# How can we use HubSpot or HighriseCRM with Office 365 and German MS Cloud?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, outlook-web-app, crm

We use Office 365 with the additional option of being hosted in the german MS cloud.

Now we would like to connect our CRM tools (HubSpot and HighriseHQ) with Office 365. Unfortunately those tools always point to https://login.microsoftonline.com (which is the US login page). Once I type in my email address there, it cant find my login (bc we are in the german MS Cloud) and its also not redirecting to the german one.

Now MS told me that I could fix this by setting a CNAME in my DNS settings:
`from msoid.mydomain.de to login.microsoftonline.de`

Unfortunately this didnt help. Any ideas how we could fix this?